# Xpath for Log-in

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click on "Log in" link present on home page of "stackoverflow" using xpath as show as below. But no success

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'log in')]")).click();

Please help what i m missing here.

- Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the following xpath:

```
//a[@class='login-link'][text()='log in']
```

I tried personally and it worked with me. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The xpath which you have used in your question returns two webelements:

```
<a href=​"https:​/​/​stackoverflow.com/​users/​login?returnurl=http%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2f" class=​"js-gps-track" data-gps-track=​"site_switcher.click({ item_type:​11 }​)​">​log in​</a>​

<a href=​"https:​/​/​stackoverflow.com/​users/​login?returnurl=http%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2f" class=​"login-link">​log in​</a>​
```

that's why selenium is not able to click on that.So use

```
//a[@class='login-link'][text()='log in']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```java
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='login-link' and .='log in']").click();
```

Above XPath match `<a>` tag having `class` attribute equals `"login-link"` and inner text equals `"log in"`.

General tip: always prefer `.` over `text()`. There are very rare situations when you have to filter element specifically by using `text()`.